# Parse html in Flutter using HTML lib

Tags: html, flutter

I'm using HTML 0.15.0  to parse HTML page content and show it in the Flutter app.

I managed to parse HTML page but I don't know how to show the content in the app.

I can print the HTML tags in the log only.

I'm asking how to show those tags as an HTML page in my app

This is my code

```
var document = parse(
      '<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!');
print(document.outerHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flutter_html (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)
Therefor you could use the widget:

```
var htmlData = '<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!'';

Html(
     data: htmlData,
);
```

The variable htmlData can contain the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_html package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html). It offers you a widget called 'Html' and you don't have to parse it just use it with string (I recommend you to use it with raw string):

```
Html(
  data: r"""<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!""",
),
```